# Sequential has no attribution "validation_data"

Tags: keras

I download and run the file from the link below
https://github.com/keunwoochoi/keras_callbacks_example

But the it has the error "Sequential has no attribute "validation_data"". Can anyone explain for me?

Comment: Note that the repo is now up to date.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0])`. That is what worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can always check what is in the object with `dir()`.

I had the same problem using `self.model.validation_data`. Checking with `dir(self.model)` showed me that there was indeed no attribute `validation_data` for my particular problem. But then checking `dir(self)` I could find it.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue.

here is the solution:

1. use self.validation_data in your custom callback class
2. provide validation_data = (x,y) in your fit method.

if point 2 is not done, self.validation_data will be empty.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This would work on the object of type `keras.engine.training.Model`.

Try `self.model.validation_data`

Answer (score 0):

Try `self.validation_data` instead of `self.model.validation_data` for Keras 2.0 and after.

You'll also have to define `validation_data` within `fit()`. Using `train_test_split`, `validation_data=(X_test, y_test)`.

Example: https://www.kaggle.com/yassinealouini/f2-score-per-epoch-in-keras