# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable - error at Keras custom callback class

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am getting this error when I am defining a custom callback function.

```
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Code sample

```
class Metrics(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):     
  def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self._data = []
  def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        X_val, y_val = self.validation_data[0], self.validation_data[1]
        y_predict = np.asarray(model.predict(X_val))
        y_val = np.argmax(y_val, axis=1)
        y_predict = np.argmax(y_predict, axis=1)
        self._data.append({
          'val_jaccard': jaccard(y_val, y_predict),
          'val_f1': f1_score(y_val, y_predict),
          'val_precision': recall_score(y_val, y_predict),
          'val_jaccard': precision_score(y_val, y_predict),
     })
    return

metrics = Metrics()
model.fit((item for item in image_data),steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, 
     epochs=20, validation_data = (item for item in image_data_val), validation_steps = valid_step , callbacks = [metrics], verbose=2)
```

Previously I was getting another error: `"AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'validation_data'.` In order to solve that error, I removed `self.model.validation_data` with `self.validation_data` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48456180/sequential-has-no-attribution-validation-data). After which I landed up to this error. I am not able to understand the source of this error

Keras version is 2.2.4

Complete traceback as requested

```
Epoch 1/20

Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseSession._Callable.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.client.session.BaseSession._Callable object at 0x7f8fbe48fa20>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1473, in __del__
    self._session._session, self._handle)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.CancelledError: (None, None, 'Session has been closed.')
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseSession._Callable.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.client.session.BaseSession._Callable object at 0x7f8fbe42f2e8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1473, in __del__
    self._session._session, self._handle)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.CancelledError: (None, None, 'Session has been closed.')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-102-43fa8dafc96c> in <module>()
      5     model.fit((item for item in image_data),steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=20,
      6                     validation_data = (item for item in image_data_val),
----> 7                     validation_steps = valid_step , callbacks = [metrics], verbose=2)
      8     eval_model=model.evaluate(image_batch, label_batch)
      9     eval_model

4 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    671           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
    672           shuffle=shuffle,
--> 673           initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
    674     if training_utils.is_eager_dataset_or_iterator(x):
    675       # Make sure that y, sample_weights, validation_split are not passed.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1431         shuffle=shuffle,
   1432         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
-> 1433         steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
   1434 
   1435   def evaluate_generator(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py in model_iteration(model, data, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch, mode, batch_size, steps_name, **kwargs)
    329     if mode == ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    330       # Epochs only apply to `fit`.
--> 331       callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
    332     progbar.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
    333 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
    309     logs = logs or {}
    310     for callback in self.callbacks:
--> 311       callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
    312 
    313   def on_train_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):

<ipython-input-101-71d6af0b20ff> in on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs)
     14 
     15   def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
---> 16         X_val, y_val = self.validation_data[0], self.validation_data[1]
     17         y_predict = np.asarray(model.predict(X_val))
     18         y_val = np.argmax(y_val, axis=1)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

UPDATE

Based on the suggestion, I am using keras for callback i.e `class Metrics(keras.callback.Callback)`. After this solution, my original error is gone but I am getting another error which is `AttributeError: 'Metrics' object has no attribute 'on_train_batch_begin'`
I don't really know this error.

The traceback for the new error is

```
    Epoch 1/20

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-60-43fa8dafc96c> in <module>()
      5     model.fit((item for item in image_data),steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=20,
      6                     validation_data = (item for item in image_data_val),
----> 7                     validation_steps = valid_step , callbacks = [metrics], verbose=2)
      8     eval_model=model.evaluate(image_batch, label_batch)
      9     eval_model

3 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    671           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
    672           shuffle=shuffle,
--> 673           initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
    674     if training_utils.is_eager_dataset_or_iterator(x):
    675       # Make sure that y, sample_weights, validation_split are not passed.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1431         shuffle=shuffle,
   1432         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
-> 1433         steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
   1434 
   1435   def evaluate_generator(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py in model_iteration(model, data, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch, mode, batch_size, steps_name, **kwargs)
    258       # Callbacks batch begin.
    259       batch_logs = {'batch': step, 'size': batch_size}
--> 260       callbacks._call_batch_hook(mode, 'begin', step, batch_logs)
    261       progbar.on_batch_begin(step, batch_logs)
    262 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in _call_batch_hook(self, mode, hook, batch, logs)
    245     t_before_callbacks = time.time()
    246     for callback in self.callbacks:
--> 247       batch_hook = getattr(callback, hook_name)
    248       batch_hook(batch, logs)
    249     self._delta_ts[hook_name].append(time.time() - t_before_callbacks)

AttributeError: 'Metrics' object has no attribute 'on_train_batch_begin'
```

Comment: I suggest u follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61686275/10375049

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a bug in `tf.keras`, they deprecated the `validation_data` parameter and no longer set the `validation_data` of the callback, its always set to None.

Your option is not to use `tf.keras` and just use the official `keras` package, I tested your code and it works in Keras 2.2.4. Alternatively you could also just pass your validation data to the `__init__` of your callback and set it there.

Comment: @mdaoust who is they? Haven't seen such change in Keras. Also I don't see where in the original post there is a generator. Keras also accepts the steps parameters in fit but ignores them.

Comment: Right, I could have been clearer in my other comment (fixed). `(item for item in image_data)` is a python generator. There's no way to know how long it is. `Model.fit` is prety clear that it [supports generators](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)

Comment: They (the keras authors) have merged all the functionality of `fit_generator` into `fit`. Note that they (the poster) are passing generators, so I don't think this is the problem

Comment: @mdaoust that link is for TensorFlow 2.0, here I get conflicting information because the OP claims to be using Keras 2.2.4, and I could reproduce the problem with tf.keras from tensorflow 1.14. Note that the version in tf.keras is '2.2.4-tf', not '2.2.4'

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I have tried your solution and now I am getting this error  'AttributeError: 'Metrics' object has no attribute 'on_train_batch_begin' My keras version is 2.2.4

Comment: @user3050590 are you sure its 2.2.4 and not 2.2.4-tf?

Comment: Yes I am importing keras and using keras instead of tf.keras

Comment: @user3050590 Then update your question, because the errors all point to you using tf.keras.

Comment: @user3050590 The error messages still point to tf.keras, you are possibly mixing keras and tf.keras and that is not supported.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197676/discussion-between-user3050590-and-matias-valdenegro).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can solve this by passing the `validation_dataset` to your `Metrics` class instead of relying on.. How was `self.validation_data` supposed to get set?